# Link two Facebook apps to a single Firebase project

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

We have two different iOS apps. They are connected to two Facebook applications for users to be able to login.
We would like to use those two apps with our single firebase project. But we were unable to bind two Facebook apps to Firebase - there is only an input for a single one.
Are there any ways or workarounds to add two Facebook apps to a Firebase project or to somehow solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. A Facebook "app" is a Firebase "project", and one Firebase "project" can be linked to at most one Facebook "app".

Typically this is because all Firebase apps within a Firebase project share the same resources (Database, Storage, and Auth), the exception being Analytics and Crash Reporting, which definitely make sense on a per-app basis.

For multiple apps using different resources (like in test, staging, etc.), we recommend using different Firebase projects, which could then link to different Facebook Apps (or could use the same Facebook App, and add two bundle IDs).

Do you have a use case outside of this general framework?

Comment: I have a development and product app which has different applicationId so we can install both on the same device for testing purposes. However Facebook Provider would cause conflict and would not allow 2 apps having the same provider id to be installed. Hence I created a Test App under my Main Facebook App.... but they now have different facebook app id. Obviously i can't login firebase using the test app id since FIrebase doesn't support multiple facebook id

Comment: I am developing apps helping people to prepare for their UK theory test. We have an app for each vehicle category in order to market them efficiently. One app for all categories wouldn't work. Hence, we have a Facebook app for each of them. However, we would like to attach them to a single Firebase project. There are 2 reasons for this: 1) user might take the car theory test and then the motorcycle theory test. Why ask them to signup twice? 2) Some questions are identical for cars and motorcycles. Hence, it makes sense to store everything in one database

Comment: Hi, any limitations to use multiple firebase projects in single application

Comment: this is definitely wrong behavior (as always with facebook APIs). Hope they'd fix it one day